# How can I use script.js and jquery-latest.min.js together?

Tags: javascript

I am using a template that use the following code for menu list.
`<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'/>`

Now I am trying to add quiz in the document that uses the followig code.
`<script src='script.js'/>`

One I add both the second one stops working.

Can anyone please help me how can I use both simultaneously?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproductible example : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Is there any errors in console?